# How do I pass a javascript variable in a get statement?

Tags: javascript, php, variables, scope, get

I want to pass the variable testVar into the get statement so I can compare the value of it with the PHP variable param. When I log testVar in the console, I get undefined. I am very new to programming so any help would be appreciated.

```
var testVar= "hello"
;

$.get('schools.php', function (param) {
    console.log(testVar) //This gives me 'undefined'
    if (param[1]== testVar){
      console.log("it is working!")
    }                   
})
```

Comment: use semicolon at end `var testVar= "hello";`

Comment: @kumar Oops that was an error in copying my code. Do you know how I can pass the testVar down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I try this and work, hope this help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxEC6.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a scope problem. The variable inside the function is different from the global, so, therefore, it gets reassigned inside your function.